# How to center only \subsection{} while all other section types remain aligned to left?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

The question is essentially above. How can I only center a specific section type while all others remain in the standard formatting?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\section{Blabla} %this one should NOT be centered
\subsection{xyz} %this one should be centered
\subsubsection{abc} %this one should NOT be centered
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The solution depends (or can depend…) on the documentclass you want to use

Comment: I thing taht should be doable using the `titlesec`

Comment: Or by using `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to patch `\subsection`.

Comment: Or natively if you use KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the package `titlesec`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\titleformat{\subsection}% sectioning command
{\large\bfseries\filcenter}% format
{\thesubsection}% label
{1ex}% label separation
{} %code before

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Blabla} %this one should NOT be centered
    \subsection{xyz} %this one should be centered
    \subsubsection{abc} %this one should NOT be centered    

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much! :)